# Ros + openstreetmap (osm cartography package)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is anyone knows how to work with ROS and Open Street Map ? I have ROS indigo.

The package is here:
http://wiki.ros.org/osm_cartography

I would like to have something like on this picture:
[image description http://wiki.ros.org/osm_cartography?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=prc-rviz-small.png](http://wiki.ros.org/osm_cartography?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=prc-rviz-small.png)

My code for now is the following but doesn't work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 
ros::init(argc, argv, "osm");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<geographic_msgs::GetGeographicMap>("geographic_msgs");
geographic_msgs::GetGeographicMap srv;

srv.request.url = "package://home/user/map.osm";
if(client.call(srv))
{
     ROS_INFO("connected");
}
else
{
     ROS_ERROR("failed");

}

return 0;
```

}

Thanks you so much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210571/ros-+-openstreetmap-(osm-cartography-package)/) by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) on 2015-11-23**:
after lunching the file, it does not show any picture. Should I run RViz and then what should add in Rviz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That package comes with a demo launch file ([source](https://github.com/ros-geographic-info/open_street_map/blob/master/osm_cartography/launch/viz_osm.launch)) which starts the visualization, and you could start from there.

---

Originally posted by [Chris L](https://answers.ros.org/users/1645/chris-l/) with karma: 61 on 2015-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0